# can import numpy, matplotlib modules in shell, but not from terminal

Tags: python

I am running python3.5 on a RPi3 and have installed matplotlib and numpy.  I can import when in the shell, but not from within the terminal, per below:

```
Python 3.5.3 (default, Sep 27 2018, 17:25:39) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>>
```

.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3 -V
Python 3.5.3
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ import numpy as np
bash: import: command not found
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ import numpy
bash: import: command not found
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
bash: import: command not found
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

Any ideas on why this would be the case?

Comment: `python3 -V` runs once to print the version then exits. Use `python3` with no special flags to get an interpreter shell. Or code your python stuff in a file with `nano myprog.py` then run it with `python3 myprog.py`.

Answer (score 4):

To run python inside a Linux terminal, you first have to execute python using the command `python3`.

Example on my Raspberry Pi:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ python3
Python 3.2.3 (default, Mar 25 2017, 13:24:50)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print("Test")
Test
>>> exit()
pi@raspberrypi ~ $
```

*Changed to python 3 example after @Dougie 's comment.*

Comment: We should all be encouraging new programmers to forget about python2 and always use `python3` for their new code.